Is it possible to create a Go module as a fork of a non-Go repo?
Is it possible to create a Go module as a fork of a data-only non-Go module?
For example, given the following non-Go repo with only data files:
https://github.com/org1/repo1
is it possible to create the following fork with go mod init as github.com/org2/repo2, and Go code with embed directives:
https://github.com/org2/repo2 ?
I've tried doing this and received a lot of errors attempting to import github.com/org2/repo in another module, e.g. github.com/org3/repo3 along the lines of the following:
% go mod tidy
go: downloading github.com/org2/repo2 v0.0.1
go: github.com/org3/repo3 imports
    github.com/org2/repo2: github.com/org2/repo2@v0.0.1: verifying go.mod: github.com/org2/repo2@v0.0.1/go.mod: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/org2/repo2@v0.0.1: 404 Not Found
[ many more error lines ]

More generally, what is a way to created a module to embed data files in another non-Go repo while maintaining ability to merge upstream changes (for data files)?

Without a go.mod it's just not a go module so you can't treat it like a go module. Maybe you can add the data repo as a Git submodule to your project and try it out?

You can only embed files and directories that are directly inside the current module. The only way to achieve what you want would be to add a go.mod to your fork and use vendoring.
Alternatively, you can add go file in your fork and embed from there, then export the Go variables.

Try using this as insecure repo
export GOPRIVATE=github.com/org3/repo3
export GOINSECURE=github.com/org3/repo3
And so on it will help you build your code without verify from go sum
